# Slower data transfer with parallel TCP connections

Tags: objective-c, sockets, networking, tcp, asyncsocket

I used the TCP AsyncSocket to transfer a large file from one machine to another using local connection (using host as local IP address).

First, I did the setup for single TCP socket connection and felt data transfer rate is slow. Its around 1mb/sec.

To make it faster I created 10 TCP sockets (Connecting on separate ports on separate threads) and started reading the partitions of file simultaneously. But It didn't make any difference. Transfer rate is almost same as that of single TCP socket connection (Or even slower).

Any idea ? Why multiple TCP sockets is not transferring data in parallel ? Any ways or suggestions to transfer file fast over TCP ?

Answer (score 4):

Parallelizing an I/O operation only helps if the I/O channel isn't saturated and the task is single-core bound.

Quite likely, adding additional I/O channels will actually slow things down as you now have multiple clients competing for a scarce resource.

What you need to figure out is *where is your bottleneck*?   Only once you've quantified the *actual* cause of your performance issue will you be able to fix it.

Comment: Thanks. I tried with FTP, Netcat etc. And I received almost similar data transfer speed. Other factors like routers and number of active clients is also making slight difference. So, its fine.